# Average values on duplicate records

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following input table

| Custid | transactions | price | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12456 | 2300 | 21 | 48300 |
| 12456 | 5200 | 29 | 150800 |
| 78901 | 3000 | 30 | 90000 |
| 676512 | 5200 | 24 | 124800 |
| 676512 | 7400 | 18 | 133200 |

where the custid has duplicates . There is a need to remove the duplicates and find the average of the transactions field and the price field for the custid that has more than 1 record and recalculate the revenue as ((new avg)transactions *(newavg) price)

**Output table**

| Custid | transactions | price | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12456 | 3750 | 25 | 93750 |
| 78901 | 3000 | 30 | 90000 |
| 676512 | 6300 | 21 | 132300 |

**Python code tried**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 .pd.read_csv("file1.csv")

df2=df1[custid].value_counts()

df1[transactions]=np.where(df2[count]>1,df1[transactions].mean())
df1[price]=np.where(df2[count]>1,df1[price].mean())
df1[revenue]=df1[transactions]*df1[price]
```

Comment: groupby and find the mean

Comment: This is not related to your question, but what earthly good is "average revenue"?  Wouldn't you always want to know "total revenue"?  You've lost information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby on custid, and mean for the transaction and price
then calculate the revenue

```
df2=df.groupby('Custid').mean().astype(int).reset_index()
df2['revenue'] = df2['transactions'] * df2['price']
df2
```

```
    Custid  transactions    price   revenue
0   12456           3750    25        93750
1   78901           3000    30        90000
2   676512          6300    21       132300
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveed!..Really appreciate your help!